# How to print unique values in a list?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

This is my list:

```
premier_league = [
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Aguero'],
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Mahrez'],
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Sterling'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Mane'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Salah'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Jota'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Ziyech'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Werner'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Abraham']
                 ]
```

I'm trying to get a new list which contains only the name of the football clubs once. This is my code:

```
clubs = []
for club in premier_league:
    clubs.append(club[0])
    
print(clubs)
```

**This is my output:**

```
 ['Manchester City', 'Manchester City', 
'Manchester City', 'Liverpool', 
'Liverpool', 'Liverpool', 
'Chelsea', 'Chelsea', 'Chelsea']
```

**This is my desired output**

```
['Manchester City', 'Liverpool', 'Chelsea']
```

Comment: What did you find when you searched stackoverflow for ideas?

Comment: I searched for 'filter unique values' but I did not receive the desired answers.

Comment: Make `clubs` a set instead of a list.

Comment: Note that his desired example is a list in original order, so just applying `set` is the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply get unique items by:

```
premier_league = [
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Aguero'],
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Mahrez'],
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Sterling'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Mane'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Salah'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Jota'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Ziyech'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Werner'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Abraham']
                 ]

clubs = []
for club in premier_league:
    clubs.append(club[0])
    
uniq_clubs = list(set(clubs))

print(uniq_clubs)
```

output：

```
['Chelsea', 'Liverpool', 'Manchester City']
```

Comment: I get an empty list when I use your solution

Comment: @TangerCity above code prints correct output

Comment: Thank you. Can you re-open my question?

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted a longer way of doing this, try this:

```python
premier_leauge = [
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Aguero'],
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Mahrez'],
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Sterling'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Mane'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Salah'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Jota'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Ziyech'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Werner'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Abraham']
                 ]

clubs = []

for club in premier_leauge:
    clubs.append(club[0])

clubs = list(dict.fromkeys(clubs))

print(clubs)
```

Comment: This only produces the same order in Python 3.6+. For older Pythons, the result is unordered.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
premier_league = [
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Aguero'],
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Mahrez'],
                 ['Manchester City', '1', 'Sterling'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Mane'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Salah'],
                 ['Liverpool', '2', 'Jota'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Ziyech'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Werner'],
                 ['Chelsea', '3', 'Abraham']
                 ]
```

If you **do not care about order**, you can just use a set:

```
>>> set(set(sl[0] for sl in premier_league)
{'Liverpool', 'Chelsea', 'Manchester City'}
```

Which can be turned into a list *where the order is likely different than your original list*:

```
>>> list(set(sl[0] for sl in premier_league))
['Chelsea', 'Manchester City', 'Liverpool'] # note order likely has changed...
```

If you **do care about order** there are several things you can do:

Python 3.6+:

```
 >>> list({}.fromkeys(sl[0] for sl in premier_league))
 ['Manchester City', 'Liverpool', 'Chelsea']
```

Python older than 3.6, several ways:

1 Use an OrderedDict fromkeys method:

```
from collections import OrderedDict 
list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(sl[0] for sl in premier_league))
```

2 The slightly hacky set.add method in a list comprehension:

```
seen=set()
[e[0] for e in premier_league if not (e[0] in seen or seen.add(e[0]))]
```

3 Use groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby
[k for k,v in groupby(premier_league, key=lambda sl: sl[0])]
```

All three of those print:

```
['Manchester City', 'Liverpool', 'Chelsea']
```